# jQuery ScrollTop After Delay

Tags: jquery, ajax, animation, scrolltop

This code is working nicely to create smooth scroll to the next anchor on my page.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">  
    $("#blockTwo").on("click", ".child", function( e ) {
         $('html, body').delay(800).animate({
         scrollTop: $('#scrollThree').offset().top
         }, 1500, "swing"); 
    });
    </script>
```

However, because the content in the anchor element is being loaded via ajax after the click event the animation has a jump mid way through. I thought I could circumnavigate this issue by adding a delay to the animation so that the content is loaded before the animation begins. Not sure if this is either a good idea or feasible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to place the event listener on the parent and have it bubble up once the element is placed on the page via `ajax`.

Notice the 2nd parameter of `on()`:

```
$(".parentElement").on("click", ".child", function( e ) {
```

Thus, for your specific example:

```
$("#blockOne").on("click", ".child", function( e ) {
```

This way, when `.click` gets loaded in via the ajax, it'll have a listener given to it by its static parent `#blockOne`. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Hi. Many thanks for your answer. I am sorry but I don't 100% understand and what I tried with your idea didn't work. Is there any chance you could just outline your idea in a little more detail. Sorry, thanks!

Comment: can you include your `html`? just up to the `div` where you place the dynamic content

Comment: I have made an edit that is specific to your `html` :)

Comment: There is still a slight jump very occasional so I have added a delay before the scroll kicks in although I am not sure I have implemented it in the best way. I have inserted it before the .animate function, is this correct?

`<script type="text/javascript">  
$("#blockTwo").on("click", ".child", function( e ) {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    $('html, body').delay(800).animate({
        scrollTop: $('#scrollThree').offset().top
    }, 1500, "swing"); 
});
</script>`